# "Console configuration "myConf" does not exist" when importing a project from SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, svn

I written a DAL Maven Java library which abstracts the access to a DB. 
Moreover, I configured the Hibernate Tool in Eclipse so that I can generate the Entity classes from the DB connection.
Here is the Hibernate connection set in Eclipse. As you can see, there is no reference to any project

[image]

The project is committed on a SVN server.

Now I'm trying to import this project into another computer with Eclipse and the Hibernate Tools. In the Hibernate Tools perspective of this other Eclipse I didn't set the same Hibernate connection "myConf" because I don't want this Eclipse to generate Entity classes.

The problem is that when importing the DAL project from SVN I get the following error in the Problem panel

```
Console configuration "myConf" does not exist
```

It seems that the project links it self to the Hibernate connection even though the connection itself isn't linked to any project.

I also tried setting to "`<None>`" the default Hibernate Console configuration and disabling the Hibernate support in the project's properties (Properties > Hibernate Settings) like in the image below

[image]

but after saving the property configuration and reopening the Hibernate Settings panel I get the flag enabled again; the problem remains.

Is there any documented bug about this strange behaviour. I think this is a very annoying problem because it obliges me to build a Hibernate Configuration (even when not needed) on every computer and with the same name.

ADD: I run Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 with Hibernate Tools version 3.7.1.Final-v20140303-0022-B124.

Thank you

Giulio

Comment: I tried importing the project in a Eclipse Kepler instance without the Hibernate Tools. In this case the problem doesn't arise, so it seems it is a Hibernate Tools' issue.

Do you know any bug related to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In the Hibernate Settings (`Properties` -> `Hibernate Settings`):

1. Check  the option `Enable Hibernate Support`.
2. Under `Default Hibernate Console Configuration`, if `config` is already defined select it else go to `Run` -> `Run Configurations` and define new configuration in `Hibernate Console Configuration`. Specify the project name. Select `JPA Project Configured Connection` in the `Database connection`, click `Apply` and return to the `Hibernate Settings` settings page.
3. Restart eclipse or `Clean` your project.

**Update:**
Try this as well:

Open .project file in the imported project from svn and any references you find in nature and build parameters remove them. *<\nature>org.hibernate.eclipse.console.hibernateNature<\nature> //or on the lines myconf.* Do same thing in .classpath file as well.

Comment: Hi @Prasad. This way the problem still remain. In fact when I'll import this project in one another Eclipse instance (different by mine), it will complain again about the missing configuration. 

I would prefer to not link a configuration to the project.

Comment: I'm sorry, neither the updated solution works for me. Eclipse still complainf for the lack of the configuration.